# SwiftUI load very long list in async way

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, list, swiftui

I've a navigation and detail view that is sending a dictionary of date (key) and array of an struct (but it's not important the struct, it contains array of string and other stuff.

If I send a very very long dictionary, the app is freezing in the selected row and the detail appears once the List finished to load each record.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var selectedChat: [Date: [TextStruct]]? // you can try with [Date: [String]]? 

    var body: some View {

           List
           {                                    
              ForEach(self.selectedChat.keys.sorted(), id: \.self)
              { key in //section data
                  Section(header:                                                                                       
                     Text("\(self.selectedChat[key]![0].date)
                  {                                                                                                        
                        ForEach(self.selectedChat[key]!,  id:\.self) {sText in
                             // my ChatView(sText) ....                                      
                  }
               }
            }
     }
```

I've tried to load some rows at the start by adding this var

```
@State private var dateAndText: [Date: [TextStruct]] = [:]
```

substitute the code above (self.selectedChat) whit self.dateAndText and on .onAppear:

```
.onAppear {
    if let chat = self.selectedChat {

           let keysDateSorted = chat.allText.keys.sorted()
           self.chatLeader = chat.chatLeader

           for key in keysDateSorted.prefix(30) {
               self.dateAndText[key] = chat.allText[key]
           }


            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
                 self.dateAndText = chat.allText

                 self.progressBarValue = 1
            }

       }
}
```

With this solution, once I push the row, immediately I can see the first 30 records, and it is ok, but I can't scroll until all the records are loaded. I know there is a way to load the array only if the user is scrolling at the end of the list, but I want to load all the list also if the user don't scroll at the end.

So, there is a way to load the list partially (like send and update the array each 100 records) and in async way (in order to don't freeze the display for bad user experience)?

Comment: it is not SwiftUI specific ... just limit what you show to the user in your business logic and model. Use SwiftUI (or different ui system) for presentation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly running into the issues described and fixed [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui) by Paul Hudson.

SwiftUI is trying to animate all of the changes so if you use his hack around the issue it should work but you will lost all animations between changes of the list.
Apple devs responded to him and Dave DeLong who were discussing it on Twitter, they said that it is definitely an issue on their end that they hope to fix.

tldr of the article:
Add `.id(UUID())` to the end of your `List`'s initializer.